# How to add property in log4j.xml file to include pool and thread size?

Tags: selenium, maven, log4j, log4j2

I have a Selenium-jbehave maven Test Automation framework. With the recent log4j vulnerability, I had to update from old slf4j version to latest 2.16. Before I was utilizing parent framework for logging. Now I had to create log4j2.xml file.

This is how my current log is printing

```
}{2021-12-16 11:04:04,582 INFO TestContext - language added to context.
```

This is what I am expecting

```
[pool-9-thread-1] 16 Dec 2021 12:14:22,205 INFO TestContext - language added to context.
```

What do I need to add in my properties file to display Pool and thread size as given? Only property I have currently in my log4j2.xml file is:

```
<Appenders>
        <Console name="Console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the [documentation of `PatternLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout): what you are looking for is the thread's name `%t`.